# Dynamically change subview

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Using EmberJs I have to create a view that can contains a player (as Youtube, Photosynth, Html COntent, ecc.) and it has to change dynamically based on controller property that contains the item to play.

I have created some views that are the player for each type of content, like in this example

```
App.basePlayer = Em.View.extend({
    templateName : 'base'
  });

App.playerEmpty= App.basePlayer.extend({
    templateName : 'empty'
  });

App.player1= App.basePlayer.extend({
    templateName : 'p1'
  });

App.player2= App.basePlayer.extend({
    templateName : 'p2'
  });
```

Now i have to create a view that can append one of this views in its content.
If the view is a normal Ember.View that binds in its content a view stored in a property, it works on initialization, but obviously if I set a new view, it will not re-rendered.

To solve this problem I created a ContainerView that contains the player :

```
App.IndexView = Em.CollectionView.extend({

  childViews: ['header', App.playerEmpty],

  header: Em.View.extend({
    templateName : 'h'
  })

});
```

Then I also created 2 methods that when the property Item in the controller is updated, they remove the old player view and add new one consistent with the type of item of controller.

```
  onItemChange : function(){

    var item = this.get('controller.item'),
        playerClass = null;


    if(item === null){
      playerClass = App.playerEmpty;
    }

    else if(item instanceof App.Item1){  
      playerClass = App.player1;
    }
    else if(item instanceof App.Item2){  
      playerClass = App.player2;
    }

    this.setPlayerView(playerClass);


  }.observes('controller.item'),


  setPlayerView: function(playerClass){

    var v =this.get('childViews').find(function(item, index, enumerable){
      return item instanceof App.basePlayer;
    });

    this.get('childViews').removeObject(v);

    this.get('childViews').pushObject(playerClass.create());

  }
```

It's good solution or there's some better?

Here there is an Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/naxuboyi/4/edit

Comment: Pantera's answer worked for me, will you please mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred pattern for writing code in Ember.js is to have your views depend on properties in your models. Because of Embers' [binding abilities](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/) those changes are automatically reflected in your views.

In your case, I created a single player view which sets its template based on the item. Now you only have a single player view and no observer code in your collection view:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.player = Em.View.extend({
  templateName : function() {
  item = this.get('content');
    if(item === null){
      return 'empty';
    }
    else if(item instanceof App.Item1){  
      return 'p1';
    }
    else if(item instanceof App.Item2){  
      return 'p2';
    } else {
      return 'base';
    }
  }.property('content')
});

App.IndexView = Em.CollectionView.extend({

  childViews: ['header', App.player],

  header: Em.View.extend({
    templateName : 'h'
  })

});

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend();

App.Item1 = Em.Object.extend({
  type : 1
});

App.Item2 = Em.Object.extend({
  type : 2
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  item: null,

  actions : {
    setItem : function(idx){
      switch(idx){
        case 0:
            this.set('item', null);
          break;
        case 1:
            this.set('item', App.Item1.create());
          break;
        case 2:
            this.set('item', App.Item2.create());
          break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This is the simple solution. If your different player views require more complicated behavioral changes and truly need different view classes then look into [programmatic creation of child views](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html#toc_programmatic-creation-of-child-views), but avoid the observers.